# How to change style of a title with python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, styles, docx

I'm using python-docx but I don't understand or retrieve any way to change the style (from bold to normal) of the title. My code is:

```
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.dml.color import ColorFormat
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

#format only the filename as return text
def format_filename(fname):
    index = fname.rfind('\\')
    font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,0,0)
    #IF statement for structuring the fine name
    if index>0:
        filename = fname[index + 1, len(fname)]
    else:
        index = fname.rfind('/')
        filename = fname[index + 1 : len(fname)]
    return filename

#print all the file into docx
def print_file(file):
    font.bold = False
    font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)
    cnt = 0
    fp = open(file, 'r')
    #read all the file and use every single line
    for line in fp.readlines():
        cnt += 1
        #if it's the first line add paragraph
        if cnt == 1:
            paragraph = document.add_paragraph(line)
        #else continue the paragraph
        else:
            paragraph.add_run(line)

#open file
document = docx.Document()
filepath = '../cap1/prg1.txt'

# set the font in the paragraph
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Courier New'
font.size = Pt(10.5)
font.bold = True
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,0,0)

#print as a heading the filename
filename = format_filename(filepath) #self procedure for format the filename
document.add_heading(filename , level=2)
#print all the file
print_file(filepath)

document.save('my_cake_file.docx')
```

Here is how the title looks like after coloring:

[image: title after coloring]

Comment: Can you show expected format?

Comment: image in the orignal post now

Comment: so you want to remove bold from the `prg1.txt` text?

Comment: I want to change the color from blue, that is normally my output style for Title 1, to black

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update color for `Heading 2` style. Here is the example:

```
import docx

# Create doc
document = docx.Document()

# Add black title
styles = document.styles
styles['Heading 2'].font.color.rgb = docx.shared.RGBColor(0, 0, 0)
document.add_heading('Title', level=2)

# Add text
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.add_run('text')

# Save file
document.save('output.docx')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't realize that i've tried it in a wrong way!Than you very much!!!!!